# Positional argument vs keyword argument

Tags: python, keyword-argument, positional-argument

Based on [this](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/def.html)

> A positional argument is a name that is not followed by an equal sign
> (=) and default value.
>
> A keyword argument is followed by an equal sign and an expression that
> gives its default value.

```py
def rectangleArea(width, height):
    return width * height

    
print rectangleArea(width=1, height=2)
```

**Question.** I assume that both `width` and `height` are positional arguments. Then why can we also call it with the keyword argument syntax?

Comment: "why we can also call it with keyword real argument syntax?"  Because that's the way the language works.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

That text you quote seems to be confused about two totally different things:

- Positional and keyword arguments are a feature of *calls* to a function (see [Python reference section `5.3.4 Calls`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls)).
- Default values are a feature of function *definitions,* as per [section `7.6 Function definitions`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)

I suspect the people who put together that course-ware weren't *totally* familiar with Python :-) Hence that link you provide is not a very good quality one.

---

In your *call* to your function, you're using the "keyword argument" feature (where the argument is named rather than relying on its position). Without that, values are bound to names based on order alone. So, in this example, the two calls below are equivalent:

```py
def process_a_and_b(a, b):
   blah_blah_blah()

process_a_and_b(1, 2)
process_a_and_b(b=2, a=1)
```

By further way of example, refer to the following definition and calls:

```
def fn(a, b, c=1):        # a/b required, c optional.
    return a * b + c

print(fn(1, 2))            # returns 3, positional and default.
print(fn(1, 2, 3))         # returns 5, positional.
print(fn(c=5, b=2, a=2))   # returns 9, named.
print(fn(b=2, a=2))        # returns 5, named and default.
print(fn(5, c=2, b=1))     # returns 7, positional and named.
print(fn(8, b=0))          # returns 1, positional, named and default.
```

Comment: In this context, `named` equals `keyword`.

Comment: You said *" In the call to that function, you're using the "named argument" feature."*. But then you also said *"The Python reference refers to positional and keyword arguments only in respect to a call to a function"*. So, now, I'm confused: when exactly positional and keyword arguments come into the picture? Because, as you said, in a function call, they become either positional or named. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Milan (and Fredrick), I probably shouldn't have used "named" when Python uses "keyword" - I've now fixed that. In terms of when it chooses positional/keyword, that happens in the call (not the definition) and depends on things such as whether you use `fn(10)` or `fn(param=10)`. In the definition, the presence of `=` is nothing to do with the positional/keyword aspect.

Answer (score 119):

Positional parameters, keyword parameters, required parameters and optional parameters are often confused. Positional parameters **are not the same as** required parameters, and keywords parameters **are not the same as** optional parameters.

*Positional(-only) parameters* are bound to positional arguments provided in a call, that is by position. They were introduced in [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters).

*Keyword(-only) parameters* are bound to keyword arguments provided in a call, that is by name.

*Positional-or-keyword parameters* are bound to positional arguments or keyword arguments provided in a call, that is either by position or by name.

*Required parameters* are bound to arguments provided in a call.

*Optional parameters* are bound to default arguments provided in a definition.

This is the Python syntax for declaring parameters:

```py
def f(positional_parameter, /, positional_or_keyword_parameter, *, keyword_parameter):
    pass
```

- Positional parameter that is required (since Python 3.8):

  ```py
  def f(a, /):
      pass


  f()  # error, argument is required
  f(1)  # allowed, positional argument
  f(a=1)  # error, keyword argument
  ```
- Positional parameter that is optional (since Python 3.8):

  ```py
  def f(a=2, /):
      pass


  f()  # allowed, argument is optional
  f(1)  # allowed, positional argument
  f(a=1)  # error, keyword argument
  ```
- Keyword parameter that is required:

  ```py
  def f(*, a):
      pass


  f()  # error, argument is required
  f(1)  # error, positional argument
  f(a=1)  # allowed, keyword argument
  ```
- Keyword parameter that is optional:

  ```py
  def f(*, a=1):
      pass


  f()  # allowed, argument is optional
  f(1)  # error, positional argument
  f(a=1)  # allowed, keyword argument
  ```
- Positional-or-keyword parameter that is required:

  ```py
  def f(a):
      pass


  f()  # error, argument is required
  f(1)  # allowed, positional argument
  f(a=1)  # allowed, keyword argument


  # In fact that function is the same as this one.

  def f(/, a, *):
      pass
  ```
- Positional-or-keyword parameter that is optional:

  ```py
  def f(a=1):
      pass


  f()  # allowed, argument is optional
  f(1)  # allowed, positional argument
  f(a=1)  # allowed, keyword argument


  # In fact that function is the same as this one.

  def f(/, a=1, *):
      pass
  ```

*Conclusion.* — A parameter can be required or optional but **not both at the same time**. It can also be positional, keyword, or **both at the same time**.

Comment: Did you mean `f(/,a,*)` instead of `f(*, a, /)` in  your last two examples?

Comment: what is "/" in your functions please explain.

Comment: @Lord-shiv It signifies the end of the positional only parameters, parameters you cannot use as keyword parameters. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735311/what-does-the-slash-mean-in-help-output

Comment: @Lord-shiv The order of parameters must be **positional only arguments**, then a `/`, then **positional or keyword arguments**, then a `*`, then **keyword only arguments** ([source](https://realpython.com/python-asterisk-and-slash-special-parameters/))

Answer (score 22):

A keyword argument is just a positional argument with a default value.  You must specify all arguments that don't have a default value.  In other words, keyword arguments are only "optional" because they will be set to their default value if not specifically supplied.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but can you elaborate more on why it's called a "keyword" argument?  I know "positional" argument means their position matters when you call the function.

Comment: Note that it is possible to have keyword arguments that are required (i.e., don't have default values).

Answer (score 12):

First, a **parameter** is a named entity *in* the function/method definition that specifies an argument. An **argument** is a value passed to a function.

For example,

```
def rectangle_area(height, width):
    pass

rectangle_area(argument_1, argument_2)
```

`height, width` are the function parameters, and `argument_1, argument_2` are the arguments passed to the function. When you say positional argument, you are talking about *arguments*, this has nothing to do with the function definition. `width` and `height` are (by default in Python) positional parameters *or* keyword parameters (so called positional-or-keyword parameters). Therefore, you could pass arguments either positionally or by keywords.

How you are calling/passing the value to the function determines if they are positional *arguments* or keyword *arguments*.

For the function `rectangle_area` we could call it equally like so:

```
rectangle_area(1, 2) # positional arguments
rectangle_area(width=2, height=1) # keyword arguments
```

- In the first calling, we pass values *positionally*: 1 is passed to the height and 2 to the width. That is, Python infers that when you say `1, 2` we mean height is 1 and width is 2 based on the position they are passed (i.e., in the function definition the first parameter is the `height` and the second is the `width`).
- In the second calling, we pass values by *keywords*. We are hinting to Python which parameter we are passing the argument to. In the second example, we flip the order of the arguments, yet we tell Python that height is still 1 and width is still 2. Both callings have exactly the same result.

### positional-only and keyword-only

The thing not many people know is that you can specify a positional-only parameter by using the `/` in the parameter list (example from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter)).

```
def func(positional_only1, positional_only2, /, positional_or_keyword): ...
```

Similarly, you can also have keyword-only parameters by using the `*` character.

```
def func(positional_or_keyword, *, keyword_only1, keyword_only2): ...
```

Finally, we also have var-positional and var-keyword (a.k.a *args and **kwargs respectively). Meaning, you can have arbitrary sequence of positional arguments or keyword arguments passed to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Positional arguments can be called either using values in order or by naming each. For example, all three of the following would work the same way:

```
def rectangleArea(width, height):
    return width * height

print(rectangleArea(1, 2))
print(rectangleArea(width=1, height=2))
print(rectangleArea(height=2, width=1))
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. According to the official glossary of Python [here](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html), positional argument is an argument that is not a keyword argument. The definition of the keyword argument is an argument preceded by an identifier (e.g. `name=`) in a function call or passed as a value in a dictionary preceded by `**`. These two definitions contradict your example.

Answer (score 1):

positional arguments: arguments passed to a function in correct positional order. below program understand the positional arguments of a function

```
#positional arguments example
def combine(str1, str2):
#To join str1 and str2 with str3
    str3 = str1 + str2
    print(str3)

#call combine() and pass 2 strings
combine("Well", "come")   #positional arguments
```

suppose, we passed 'come' first, 'well' second, then the result will be comewell. also, call the function 3 strings become error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some extra information to complete @Nazime Lakehal’s [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57819001/2326961).

A positional parameter that is optional cannot be followed by a positional parameter or positional-or-keyword parameter that is required:

```py
# SyntaxError.

def f(a=1, b, /):
    pass


# SyntaxError.

def f(a=1, /, b):
    pass
```

A positional-or-keyword parameter that is optional cannot be followed by a positional-or-keyword parameter that is required:

```py
# SyntaxError.

def f(a=1, b):
    pass
```

For binding a positional parameter that is optional, all previous positional parameters that are optional have to be bound, making them all effectively required. That may be the origin of the confusion of positional parameters with required parameters:

```py
def f(a=1, b=2, /):
    pass


f(1, 0)
```

For binding a keyword parameter or positional-or-keyword parameter that is optional, all other keyword parameters and positional-or-keyword parameters that are optional do not have to be bound. That may be the origin of the confusion of keyword parameters with optional parameters:

```py
def f(c=3, *, a=1, b=2):
    pass


f(b=0)


def f(a=1, b=2, *, c=3):
    pass


f(b=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Understand the keyword arguments of a function.

Keyword arguments are arguments that identify the parameters by their names.

```
#keyword arguments example: 
def employee(name, Id):
    print("Employee Name: ", name)
    print("Employee Id  : ", Id)
#call employee() and pass 2 arguments
employee(name = "inban", Id = "pay001")
employee(Id = "pay002", name = "karthik") #we can change the order args.
```

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that both width and height are positional arguments. Then why can we also call it with the keyword argument syntax?

To prevent that you can use positional-only arguments:

```
def rectangleArea(width, height, /):
    return width * height

print rectangleArea(width=1, height=2)
```

The error message would be as follows:

> TypeError: rectangleArea() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'width, height'