# configuration_model() got multiple values for keyword argument 'create_using' in Networkx 1.10

Tags: python, networkx

I was using networkx 1.9 with python 2.7 and decided to update to the latest 1.10 version.
when using the bipartite graph generator function configuration_model, I found that what I what using before :

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
import networkx.algorithms.bipartite as bipartite
aseq=[1 2 1]
bseq=[2 1 1]
G =bipartite_configuration_model(aseq,bseq, create_using=None, seed=None)
```

new version:

```
G =configuration_model(aseq, bseq, create_using=None, seed=None)

configuration_model() got multiple values for keyword argument 'create_using'
```

did not work anymore. Any idea what is the create_using= should be ? I read the source file and could not see what was needed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the difference between versions but small changes to your old version solved the issue. What I did as a change for your code is:

> the definition of aseq and bseq as they gave error:

```
aseq=[1, 2, 1] # with commas between degree sequences
bseq=[2, 1, 1]
```

> Calling the configuration_model function

```
G = bipartite.configuration_model(aseq,bseq, create_using=None, seed=None) # you had an underscore instead of a '.'
```

then with a simple color_map to differentiate the nodes belonging to each part as follows:

```
color_map = []
for n in G.nodes():
    if G.node[n]['bipartite'] == 0:
        color_map.append('blue')
    else: color_map.append('green')
```

Drawing the graph produced:

[image]

As for the create_using parameter, you can check the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.bipartite.generators.configuration_model.html#networkx.algorithms.bipartite.generators.configuration_model). it says that you can use it to determine the type of the returned graph. By default it is a multi-Graph with parallel edges.

Comment: Thank you ! About the sequence, it was indeed an error, I actually create my sequences using 'nx.utils.create_degree_sequence(3, powerlaw_sequence, exponent=2)' which results in a degree sequence with comma separation. But I understand with @Joel and your answer that writing configuration model alone without specifying bipartite indeed resulted in the error I had... but reading the graph generator section did not help in explaining that I needed to write 'bipartite.graph_generator'. Thanks again for clarifying that !

Answer (score 1):

`bipartite_configuration_model` and `configuration_model` are different commands.  Your new code calls `configuration_model`, for which there is only a single partition of nodes.

It interprets `aseq` as the degree distribution.  It then interprets the second argument as the `create_using` variable (if the second argument is optional, it can be specified either by giving a second argument in the function call, or by using a keyword in the function call [(more details)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450656/positional-argument-v-s-keyword-argument)).  So it saw that as `create_using=bseq`.  Then you explicitly passed it an additional value for `create_using`, and so it had multiple values.  You clearly don't mean to do that, hence the error.

I believe Abdallah's answer shows you what you actually want to do.

---

Additional: I doubt you really mean to do both of these calls.

```
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite
import networkx.algorithms.bipartite as bipartite
```

Comment: Indeed... not a clean code... Thanks for your help !