# i am doing a code for school (python), and the code keeps erroring

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I am writing a code in python for school and I am not very advanced with python, my whole code is a turtle-drawn board game. I want to-when a turtle reaches the last space- make a turtle (A) write , bname,"Has Won!" where bname is a user input str variable. However, this line of code:

```
A.write(bname,"HAS WON!!!", move=False, align="left", font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
```

keeps getting an error:

```
A.write(bname,"HAS WON!!!", move=False, align="left", font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
TypeError: write() got multiple values for argument 'move'
```

Anyone know how to solve this, I don't know what to do!
This is turtle by the way ;-)

Comment: What's `A.write()`? Is it a method inside some class? you need to show your code!

Comment: A is the name of a turtle it is supposed to write the text bname,"HAS WON!"

Comment: bname is a variable

Comment: its a 800 ish line code...

Comment: Please , consider to edit your post with more information about the code...

Comment: OK will do.....

Comment: the answer by Kevin solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `write` is a function whose first argument is a string, second argument is a boolean indicating whether the text should move, etc etc. In which case, it accepts `bname` as the first argument and `"HAS WON!!!"` as the second argument. Then it sees that you also provided `move=False` and gets confused because you already said `"HAS WON!!"` was the value for the second argument `move`.

Here is a simpler example of the same error occurring:

```
>>> def f(a,b):
...     return a + b
...
>>> f(4, 8, b=15)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got multiple values for argument 'b'
```

If you want bname *and* `"HAS WON!!!"` to be the first argument, then try concatenating them:

```
A.write(bname + "HAS WON!!!", move=False, align="left", font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess move is the first or second positional argument. once you are setting that by passing `bname` or `"HAS WON!!"` and the other time you are setting that by passing keyword argument `move=False`.

Good examples of about positional and keyword arguments can be found here.
[Positional argument v.s. keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450656/positional-argument-v-s-keyword-argument)