# Why won't this code that prints of all words from a file work?

Tags: python

I do not want to print of all of the contents of the file at once because I will be collecting the words later. This is my code here:

```
file = open('file analysis.txt', 'r')
chars = ''
for line in file:
    for ch in file:
        chars = chars + ch
        if ch == ' ':
            print(chars)
file.close()
```

Will be at school for a few hours so may not respond to questions straight away.

Comment: You may have meant `for ch in line` instead of `for ch in file`. Also in case of last word in a line `ch` will be `\n'` instead of space

Comment: Also, did you perhaps meant to reset `chars` back to `''` again after printing?

Answer (score 0):

You got it almost right, if you want to iterate over the lines of the file and then over each character in a line, change your second `for` to `for ch in line:`.

As kuro mentions in the comments, you are currently printing the read words only when you encounter a space character, not on newlines. The way your `print` works right now is printing all read words after each space, so a sample output might look like this:

```
Lorem 
Lorem ipsum 
Lorem ipsum dolor 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
```

If you only mean to print each new word you encounter, you probably want to reset `chars = ''` after printing. To suppress newlines after each word, you can use `print(chars, end='')`.

It is also safer to open files inside a `with` statement, that way closing the file will be handled for you.

Then your code could look like this:

```
with open('file analysis.txt', 'r') as file:
    chars = ''
    for line in file:
        for ch in line:
            chars = chars + ch
            if ch == ' ':
                print(chars, end='')
                chars = ''
```

This would give the following output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
```

Notice that you print only on spaces, so when your last word is not followed by a space, it will be read but not printed.

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

**First**, instead of using `file.open()` and `file.close()`, you should use

```
with open('file analysis.txt', 'r') as f:
```

which automatically closes the file for you. 
**Additionally**, you should use `for ch in line:` not `for ch in file:`
Because you want to print each character in the line, not each line in the file twice. **Also**, you want to reset your `chars` variable to the empty string after printing each time, so you don't print the same word multiple times. **Finally**, python's `print()` function will by default create a newline after each print statement. You can avoid this by doing `print(string, end='')` which replaces the end of line character with the empty string.

Taking all this into account, your code them becomes:

```
with open('file analysis.txt', 'r') as f:
chars = ''
for line in f:
    for ch in line:
        chars += ch
        if ch == ' ':
            print(chars, end='')
            chars = ''
```

If you're interested in learning more about the `print(string, end='')` function, look up [positional arguments vs keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450656/positional-argument-v-s-keyword-argument) For more about the with.. as statement, look [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)