# I got the following error when I executed my behave code. can someone please tell me why this issue is occuring

Tags: selenium, appium, python-behave

Error:

```
TypeError: step_impl() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'
```

Code:

```
@when('the user clicks on "Login"')
def step_impl(self,context):
    """
    :type context: behave.runner.Context
    """
    homePage.loginButton(self)
```

Comment: You are trying to invoke `step_impl()` without arguments, it need to get `context` parameter.

Comment: @Guy I think there is more to that question, it seems like the OP has created `class` and in that case `self` will be the first parameter. The question is how to add steps in `class` in `behave`

Comment: https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/630 Here is the discussion about this

Answer (score 0):

The first argument for the `step_impl` function is `context`, not `self`, hence your error. If you're interested, you can learn a little about `positional` and `keyword` arguments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450656/positional-argument-v-s-keyword-argument?lq=1).

That is,

```
@when('the user clicks on "Login"')
def step_impl(context):
    """
    :type context: behave.runner.Context
    """
    homePage.loginButton(self) # This line of code will break
```