# How to fix the error regarding matplotli.pyplot.bar()

Tags: opencv, matplotlib

I am working on a project of pedestrian detection. Here I need to implement HOG from scratch. So I went through a github and tried to implement a script. When implementing I found some errors as follow. As i am a beginner I can not quite understand the problem. Please help me out please.

```py
matplotlib.pyplot.bar(left=numpy.arange(9), height=HOG_cell_hist, align="center", width=0.8)
```

The above code shows an error message like this-

```py
TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look to the [documentation of the bar function](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) you will see:

> matplotlib.pyplot.bar(x, height, width=0.8, bottom=None, *,
>   align='center', data=None, **kwargs)

This tells you that the parameters `x` and `height` are not optional. Also, I do not see any `left` parameters which is used in your code.

I think `left` should be `x` and your code will be fixed. Unless you intended something else with the `left` argument.

The code should be like this:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.bar(x=numpy.arange(9), height=HOG_cell_hist, align="center", width=0.8)
```

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest AFAIK I cannot turned them named, but I can use them as named ones, without leaving any positional ones unused, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450656/positional-argument-v-s-keyword-argument) or am I wrong?

Comment: Oh yes you can. Sorry for the confusion. It's indeed `bar(x, height)`, and I got confused because for `plot` that wouldn't work. Feel free to restore the original answer.