# How to fix the error "TypeError: forward()... - CUDA

Tags: python, pytorch

For my bachelor thesis I need to train a network with some music similarity data using GPU and CUDA.

Tried to fix the problem several times with different approaches, but none of them worked.

```
use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()

BSG_model = bayesian_skipgram(V, EMBEDDING_DIM)

if use_cuda:
    BSG_model.cuda()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(BSG_model.parameters(), lr=0.005)
BSG_model.train()
loss_progress = []
iter_time = time.time()

dataloader = DataLoader(data, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)

print("N_batches", len(dataloader))

for epoch in range(1):
    for i, batch in enumerate(dataloader):
        batch_start = time.time()
        main_word = batch[:,0]
        context_word = batch[:,1:]

    #print("Main word:,", main_word.shape, context_word.shape)


    optimizer.zero_grad()

    if use_cuda:
        loss = BSG_model.forward(main_word.cuda(), context_word.cuda(), use_cuda=True)
    else:
        loss = BSG_model.forward(main_word, context_word)

    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    batch_end = time.time() - batch_start
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print("epoch, batch ", epoch, i)
        loss_progress.append(loss.item())  
        print(time.time()-iter_time)
        print(loss)
        iter_time = time.time()
```

"The expected result should be that the model starts to train the embeddings..."
"The output is the following:"

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-c69aba816e22> in <module>()
     34 
     35         if use_cuda:
---> 36             loss = BSG_model.forward(main_word.cuda(), context_word.cuda(), use_cuda=True)
     37         else:
     38             loss = BSG_model.forward(main_word, context_word)

 TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_cuda'
```

Comment: No, my professor has provided me with the code. P.S. I have no previous knowledge about programming... my prof. meant its not that hard so I accepted the challenge.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is quite self explanatory:

> TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_cuda'

You call `forward` function like this

```py
oss = BSG_model.forward(main_word.cuda(), context_word.cuda(), use_cuda=True)
```

with two [positional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9450656/1714410): `(main_word.cuda(), context_word.cuda()` and one [keyword arguement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9450656/1714410): `use_cuda=True`.

Keyword arguments means that when the function is declared/defined it has an argument with the **same name**. For instance:

```py
def forward(self, word, context, use_cuda):
  ...
```

Is a declaration of `forward` function with `use_cuda` argument.

However, it seems like you are calling `forward` with `use_cuda` keyword argument, but the function `forward` you are using does **not** have a `use_cuda` argument at all!

Please look carefully at the way your `BSG_model.forward` function is defined.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the forward function and now this kind of error disappears, but a new error occurs. Sorry for asking that many questions, but I have absolutely no clue what to do :/.                                                                           RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (59) : device-side assert triggered at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorMath.cu:196