# Python- class instance problem (init takes five arguments; only passing two)

Tags: python, arguments, instance, maya

I’ve been working on an IK/FK joint matching script, that I managed to finally get working correctly last month. Today start I up Maya, run the script and while the interface loads up, I received the following errors…

This one upon running loading script:

```
# Error: NameError: file <maya console> line 196: global name 'Fks' is not defined #
```

and this one upon clicking my ‘select root joint chain’ button:

```
# Error: NameError: file <maya console> line 1: name 'select_joints_afk' is not defined #
```

I’m really new to this so I really don’t understand what exactly is going on

```
class Create_Selection_Chains(object):

    def __init__(self, name, *args):
        self.Fks = Fks
        self.Ikw = Ikw
        self.Pv = ikpv
        self.name = name
        self.combined_selection = self.Fks+self.Ikw+self.Pv
        print("List created"+self.name)

    def select_joints_afk(self):

        if cmds.ls(selection = True,type=("transform",'nurbsCurve')):
            sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
            fks = sel
            fkCtrls = cmds.listRelatives(sel, allDescendents=True, type=("transform",'nurbsCurve'))
            Fks = [nurbsCurve for nurbsCurve in fkCtrls if nurbsCurve.startswith('FK') & nurbsCurve.endswith('Ctrl')]
            cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(gtF0, edit = True, tx ='' .join(sel),buttonLabel='IK OK',backgroundColor = (.5,.8,.2))
            del Fks[1]
            del Fks[2]
            Fks.extend(sel)
            print Fks

            return self.Fks 
        else:
            text = cmds.confirmDialog( title='Error', message='Must select joint', button=['OK'], 
                                        defaultButton='Ok', dismissString='No' )

    def select_joints_aikw(self):

        if cmds.ls(selection = True,type=("transform",'nurbsCurve')):

            sel=cmds.ls(selection = True)
            ikwrist = sel
            Ikw = [nurbsCurve for nurbsCurve in ikwrist if nurbsCurve.startswith('IK') & nurbsCurve.endswith('Ctrl')]
            cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(gtF1, edit = True, tx ='' .join(ikwrist),buttonLabel='IK OK',backgroundColor = (.5,.8,.2))
            cmds.select(ikwrist)
            print Ikw
            return self.ikw
        else:
            text = cmds.confirmDialog( title='Error', message='Must select joint', button=['OK'], defaultButton='Ok', 
                                        dismissString='No' )

    def select_joints_ikpv(self):

        if cmds.ls(selection = True,type=("transform",'nurbsCurve')):
            sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
            ikPvsel = sel
            ikpv = [nurbsCurve for nurbsCurve in ikPvsel if nurbsCurve.startswith('IK') & nurbsCurve.endswith('Ctrl')]
            cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(gtF2, edit = True, tx ='' .join(ikPvsel),buttonLabel='IK OK',backgroundColor = (.5,.8,.2))        
            cmds.select(ikPvsel)
            print ikpv
            return self.ikpv
        else:
            text = cmds.confirmDialog( title='Error', message='Must select joint', button=['OK'], 
                                        defaultButton='Ok', dismissString='No' )
```

I was told that if I pass the variables into the class when you instantiate it, as long as I pass the required arguments it should run fine, however upon changing

```
def __init__(self, name, *args):
```

to

```
def __init__(self, name, Fks, Ikw, ikpv):
```

I receive the following message upon loading my script in maya

```
# Error: TypeError: file <maya console> line 413: __init__() takes at least 5 arguments (2 given) #
```

line 413 is where I load my instances...:

```
left_arm_select = Create_Selection_Chains("left arm")
```

Could someone help me understand what is hapening? because I thought I was passing all my arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, calling `Create_Selection_Chains(...)` now requires three more arguments.  Why?

- `__init__(self, name, Fks, Ikw, ikpv)` requires several *positional arguments*, i.e. `name, Fks, Ikw, ikpv`
- `__init__(self, name, *args):` requires one [positional argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450656/positional-argument-v-s-keyword-argument) (`name`) and 0 to many [*arbitrary arguments*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) (`*args`).

*Solution*: pass in more values at instantiation, e.g. `Create_Selection_Chains("left arm", "foo", "bar", "baz")`

---

**Given**

```
class Create_Selection_Chains(object):

    def __init__(self, name, *args):
        self.Fks = Fks
        self.Ikw = Ikw
        self.Pv = ikpv
        self.name = name
        ...
```

As you have likely discovered, `__init__(self, name, *args)` doesn't work since `args` isn't mapped to anything and `Fks`, `Ikw` and `ikpv` are not defined.  This will throw an error.

**Code**

Consider the following as one of many options:

```
class Create_Selection_Chains:

    def __init__(self, name, fks, ikw, ikpv):
        self.name = name
        self.fks = fks
        self.ikw = ikw
        self.pv = ikpv

        ...
```

Finally, pass more values in at instantiation, e.g.:

```
left_arm_select = Create_Selection_Chains("left arm", "foo", "bar", "baz")
```

Comment: I this does remove my errors but now I can't seem to get my return values to replace the foo, bar, baz values

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  You would have to elaborate on "my return values to replace the foo, bar, baz values".

Answer (score 0):

*args is variable, your change not.
Here you have to give every argument, you defined in the init function.
You could change it to Fks=some value, IKw=some value etc. to make it an optional argument.