# generate keyword arguments from positional arguments in python

Tags: python, args, keyword-argument

Given a function definition

```
def foo(model, evaluator):
    pass 

model = ...
evaluator = ...
```

and a call site like this

```
foo(model=model, evaluator=evaluator)
```

I would like to do only

```
foo(model, evaluator)
```

as to avoid repetition but then construct keyword arguments within foo for later passing onto **kwargs parameters.

The only way I can think of is

```
def foo(*args):
    **{str(arg): arg for arg in args}
```

is this ok?

Comment: Use `locals()` to get a dictionary of local variables? Can that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `model=model` bit. The arguments are positional, they match based on their order, not necessarily their name. Leave off the equals at the call site.

```py
>>> def foo(bar, baz):
...     print('bar',bar,'baz',baz)
... 
>>> bar=2
>>> baz=3
>>> foo(bar,baz)
bar 2 baz 3
```

For more info on positional arguments: [Positional argument v.s. keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450656/positional-argument-v-s-keyword-argument)

If you want to just pass a dict to an object you can use the **arg syntax:

```
>>> def show_me(**m):
...     for k,v in m.items():
...             print(k,v)
>>> d={'x':2,'y':3}
>>> show_me(**d)
x 2
y 3
```

You have the call it with the double asterisk **d though:

```
>>> show_me(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: show_me() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: yes I know, but I need to be able to pass in the arguments in arbitrary order and combinations, which makes your solution unfeasible

Comment: I tried to put that code in a comment, but it was unreadable.
I put the code into an edit of the answer. It uses the REPL styling.
Hope that helps. :)