# How to call only the second value of a class in python, while keeping the first value as default?

Tags: python, class, arguments

In variable `y` I want to call only the second value i.e `age` while keeping the first value (`height`) as the default. How do I do that?

```
class person():
    def __init__(self, height=130, age=20):
        self.height = height
        self.age = age

    def convert_height(self):
        return self.height / 10

    def find_birth_year(self, p_year):
        return p_year - self.age


x = person(170)
y = person(, 32) # How to have default value for height here?

print(x.height, x.age)
print(y.height, y.age)
print(x.convert_height(), x.find_birth_year(2020))
print(y.convert_height(), y.find_birth_year(2020))
```

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer the most helpful and the most complete ;) for the next ones that’ll comme here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a keyword argument:

`y = person(age=32)`

Comment: no problem, consider marking it the 'correct answer' using the tick on the left if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `keyword` argument : use its name and its position in the method

```
class person():
    def __init__(self, height=130, age=20):
        self.height = height
        self.age = age
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = person(170)
    y = person(age=32)
```

Here are [some more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450656/positional-argument-v-s-keyword-argument)