# Using the = sign in variables for method calls

Tags: python

When doing a method call in Python, in which cases do you use the = sign when entering arguments?

I noticed sometimes it's:

```
object.method(argument1 = ... , argument2 = ...)
```

and other times it's

```
object.method(... , ...)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These are named arguments versus positional arguments. It's not specific to method calls, you can do it with ordinary functions as well.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Comment: They should be explained in most Python tutorials.

Comment: You can use them (a) for just being more explicit, (b) for skipping optional parameters, e.g. calling `def f(a, b=1, c=2)` as `f(42, c=3)`, or (c) for entirely unspecific `**kwargs`. You example seems to be case (a).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Positional argument vs named keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450656/positional-argument-v-s-keyword-argument#:~:text=Positional%20arguments%20are%20arguments%20that,must%20passed%20to%20the%20function.&text=In%20python%20optional%20arguments%20are%20arguments%20that%20have%20a%20default%20value.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That types of arguments are called keyword arguments, probably you've seen that as (kwargs).
In a function you can pass 2 types of args, positional arguments and keyword-arguments.
`def function(arg):`
So you have to pass inside this function a positional argument, this means that you have to pass only the value for that arg like
`function(1)` or maybe a string `function("hello")` or maybe a list and so on; This type of arg is called position arg.
When you have to specify the name of the variable inside the brackets of a function call like `function(name = "John")`, you are using the keyword args.
If you want to understand more on this topic, i suggest you to see the unpack operator in Python (*) and then *args and **kwargs.
2 words to say what *args and **kwargs do in Python, they allows you to specify an unlimited number of arguments inside a function call.

```
def function(*args, **kwargs):
   pass
function(1,2,3,"hello",[1,2,3],name="John",age=5)
```