# Fixing the error (TypeError: validation_curve() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run this code in my Google collab:

```
train_scores, test_scores = validation_curve(Ridge(), X_train_s, y_train, "alpha", param_range, scoring = "r2")
```

but I keep getting the error below:

```
TypeError: validation_curve() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given.
```

Kindly help in fixing this.

Answer (score 2):

That means that there are only 3 arguments that you can pass before giving keyword arguments.

Try to do something like that

```py
train_scores, test_scores = validation_curve(
  Ridge(),
  X_train_s, 
  y_train,
  param_name="alpha",
  param_range=param_range,
  scoring = "r2"
)
```

Have a look at example [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_validation_curve.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-validation-curve-py)

Answer (score 0):

referring to the definition of a positional argument:
[positional argument definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450656/positional-argument-v-s-keyword-argument#:%7E:text=Positional%20arguments%20are%20arguments%20that,not%20passed%20to%20the%20function.)!

the position of the "alpha" and  param_range argument is wrong:

```
validation_curve(Ridge(), X_train_s, y_train, "alpha", param_range, scoring = "r2")
```

so as a solution i propose to use a named argument.

"aphla" --> param_name="alpha"

and for the param_range --> param_range=param_range.

I found the name of the argument in [this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/learning_curve.html#validation-curve) of scikit_learn

so the solution of your problem is :

```
validation_curve(Ridge(), X_train_s, y_train, param_name="alpha", param_range=param_range, scoring = "r2")
```